# Cropping an uploaded image in php

Tags: php, crop

I want to have a bit of code that crops an image already uploaded onto the site. I have written the following code and think I am very close, just need a little help.

The php file is called with the already uploaded filename, it's dimensions, the new x,y and dimensions. From here I want to check if it is either a png or jpg then crop and replace the original file and pass back either failure (if it failed to save) or the filename.

Here is my code so far, all help would be great!

```
<?php

// We're putting all our files in a tempory directory.

$uploaddir = '../../temp_uploads/';

$targ_w = $_POST['targetWidth'];
$targ_h = $_POST['targetHeight'];
$origImage = $_POST['origImage'];

$src = $uploaddir.$origImage;

// Get the mime
$getMime = explode('.', $origImage);
$mime = end($getMime);

if ($mime==".png") {
    $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);  
} else {
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
}

$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'], $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$dst_r);
$decodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);

if (file_put_contents($src, $decodedData)) {
    echo $origImage;
} else {
    echo "failure ";
}

?>
```

Comment: What isn't working yet? Right now it's not clear what you want help with.

Comment: try this `if ($mime=="png") {` instead of `if ($mime==".png") {`

Comment: No, when it recreates the file it is corrupt / not a valid image. I think I am close

Comment: Good spot. Yeah need to change that. But I have been testing with a jpg so that won't have caused the problem

Comment: and also check `$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$dst_r);
$decodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);`

Comment: Yes your condition is wrong $mime == "png" you dont need dot prefix since you are exploding it , good one @imsiso

Comment: what is wrong with $encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$dst_r); $decodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);

Comment: @Simsy - why are you using that?

Comment: Just based of the file upload code I got to work.

Comment: I don't understand? you want to save the new image to file right? so you should use imagejpeg or imagepng for that.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work if ($mime=="png") {
 if (imagepng($dst_r,$src)) {
     echo $origImage;
 } else {
     echo "failure ";
 }
} else {
 if (imagejpeg($dst_r,$src)) {
     echo $origImage;
 } else {
     echo "failure ";
 }
}

Comment: it seems to be saving fine now. thanks. The cropping is a little off?

Comment: what can you explin more and paste a picture of that?